# What does she mean by "can I claim them as dependent"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this commercial
[TurboTax 2017 TV Commercial "Kathy Bates Scary Dependents" (Official :45) TV ad](https://youtu.be/gxYuHVDnL8o) 
she says there are kids in her house and if she can claim them as dependent. But I don't understand what she means by that and I got even more confused that the assistant responded "unfortunately you can't but you can deduct some of your moving expenses."
Is it even related?

Answer (score 2):

Here, a *dependent* is a technical term used for tax purposes. From the IRS,

> [Module 4: Dependents](https://apps.irs.gov/app/understandingTaxes/hows/tax_tutorials/mod04/tt_mod04_01.jsp)
>
> A dependent is a person other than the taxpayer or spouse who entitles the taxpayer to claim a dependency exemption.
>
> Each dependency exemption decreases income subject to tax by the exemption amount.
>
> - For 2014, the exemption amount is $3,950.
>
> A taxpayer cannot claim a dependency exemption for a person who can be claimed as a dependent on another tax return.
>
> The term "dependent" means a "qualifying child" or a "qualifying relative."

The page then goes on to list some criteria.

If she can claim the kids as dependents, then she can receive tax exemptions.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about how *taxes* work than how english works. A "dependent" is someone who relies on you for support, like a non-working spouse or a child who lives with you.

When you "claim" something on your taxes, it means you are stating that you are entitled to a reduction in your taxes for a particular reason. There are many reasons for it, and one of them is having children who rely on you for care.

The assistant is saying, that legally, the children in her home do not *qualify* as dependents, and she may not claim them on her tax forms. But, she may claim her moving expenses.

I really can't explain this much further without getting into a detailed explanation of income taxes and income tax witholding.

Answer (score 0):

She wants to get tax return by claiming those kids as her dependents. She asks whether she can show those kids, in the eyes of the law, as hers in order to get benefits or reduction while paying her taxes.

For your second question, the customer service lady tells her that she can not claim those kids as hers, and by "getting deduction for moving expenses" she means that there might be another way to get some economic benefit by showing the money she spent on moving.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Did you mean "tax reduction" or "tax refund" instead of "tax return"?

Comment: So you get benefits if you have children ?

Comment: @EliasOrozco it's not a benefit, so much as a reduction in the amount of income tax you are supposed to pay. Like I said, this is a question about *US tax policy and not english*.